# Objective-C / UIButton / SetTitle

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, retain

Does the setTitle method of UIButton retain the NSString passed as argument ?

I guess I can rely on the fact that the property is defined as:

property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) UILabel *titleLabel

In this case, I think that it does retain the string.

Thanks,
Apple92

Answer (score 1):

You can count on framework classes to retain things that they need unless otherwise documented. This is part of Cocoa's [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/). You should read that document and let it sink in, because once you understand it, basically all of your memory management questions go away — conversely, if you don't take the time to understand that document, you'll always feel uncertain. Luckily, it's pretty simple.

Also, I would be careful about relying too much on other people telling you the rules. Especially in informal settings like Stack Overflow, people have a tendency to simplify and misspeak, leading to misunderstandings — meanwhile, the official rules have been proofread many, many times over the years.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you've pretty much answered your own question there.

Not all API's retain as the original NSString may change in some way - one API may receive an NSString reference, but it's actually an NSMutableString, for exapmle.

The [Google coding standards for Objective C](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml) has a section about this, [here](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml?showone=Setters_copy_NSStrings#Setters_copy_NSStrings)